# Using case for a range of numbers in Bash

Tags: bash, switch-statement

I am trying to do the following using `case` in Bash (in Linux).

If X is between 460 and 660, output X information.

If X is between 661 and 800, do something else.

Etc.

Right now this is what I have:

```
case $MovieRes in
    [461-660]*) echo "$MovieName,480p" >> moviefinal ;;
    [661-890]*) echo "$MovieName,720p" >> moviefinal ;;
    [891-1200]*) echo "$MovieName,1080p" >> moviefinal ;;
    *) echo "$MovieName,DVD" >> moviefinal ;;
esac
```

But somehow many of the ones that are 480p, 720p or 1080p are ending with DVD instead. The variable `$MovieRes` is a simple list that shows, for each line, a number between 1 and 1200. Depending on the value, `case` decides which "case" to apply.

I would like to know how to actually use `case` to accomplish this since it is a bit confusing when dealing with ranges like this.

Comment: "But somehow many of the ones" ... I'm not quite sure which `ones` are being referred to here.  Can you clarify?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In bash, you can use the `arithmetic expression`: `((...))`

```
if ((461<=X && X<=660))
then
    echo "480p"
elif ((661<=X && X<=890))
then
    echo "720p"
elif ((891<=X && X<=1200))
then
    echo "1080p"
else
    echo "DVD"
fi >> moviefinal
```

Answer (score 38):

The bash `case` statement doesn't understand number ranges. It understands [shell patterns](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching).

The following should work:

```
case $MovieRes in
    46[1-9]|4[7-9][0-9]|5[0-9][0-9]|6[0-5][0-9]|660) echo "$MovieName,480p" >> moviefinal ;;
    66[1-9]|6[7-9][0-9]|7[0-9][0-9]|8[0-8][0-9]|890) echo "$MovieName,720p" >> moviefinal ;;
    89[1-9]|9[0-9][0-9]|1[0-1][0-9][0-9]|1200)       echo "$MovieName,1080p" >> moviefinal ;;
    *)                                               echo "$MovieName,DVD" >> moviefinal ;;
esac
```

However, I'd recommend you use an if-else statement and compare number ranges as in the other answer. A `case` is not the right tool to solve this problem. This answer is for explanatory purposes only.

Comment: Thank you dogbane. Now here is the problem, you answer correctly answered what I was looking for, but as you also mentioned, this would not be the correct way of doing it. The correct/easier way would be to use Kev's answer. Should I: 1. Accept your answer as the correct answer and give Kev a +1 or 2. Should I accept Kev answer as the correct one and give you a +1. I ask since you both somehow answer correctly.

Comment: IMO kev's answer should be accepted because that is what you (and anyone else coming to this site) should be using. But I wouldn't mind a +1! Thanks :)

Answer (score 35):

Just for the pleasure of subverting case to do as you want,
you can use `$((...))`

```
case 1 in
    $(($MovieRes<= 460)))echo "$MovieName,???";;
    $(($MovieRes<= 660)))echo "$MovieName,480p";;
    $(($MovieRes<= 890)))echo "$MovieName,720p";;
    $(($MovieRes<=1200)))echo "$MovieName,1080p";;
                       *)echo "$MovieName,DVD";;
esac >> moviefinal
```

Comment: Huh, it looks like `case 1 in` essentially equals `case true in`? That is, a case is met if the formula returns true? This is a cool use of `case`!

Comment: Nice answer! Actually we don't need `$` in parentheses: `$((MovieRes<=1200))` will work

Comment: `$`/`${}` is unnecessary on variables inside arithmetic expressions. Source: https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2004

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for the simplest solution and found it difficult to use a **case statement** with a **number range** .

Finally i found a really simple solution for **zsh** :

```
  #!/usr/bin/zsh 

 case "${var}" in

 <0-5461>)

 printf "${var} is between 0 and 5461"

 ;;

 <5462-10922>)

printf "${var} is between 5462-10922"

 ;;

 esac
```

and for **Bash** :

```
  #!/bin/bash

 case $((   

(var >= 0 && var <= 5461)      * 1 +   

(var > 5462 && var  <= 10922)   * 2)) in   

(1) printf "${var} is between 0 and 5461";; 

(2) printf "${var} is between 5461 and 10922";; 

esac
```

Hope it helps someone .

Comment: Your zsh solution was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Similar issue which might be useful to someone ... Random additional thing I just tried out where it checks also that it is an integer, for me I wanted it to have a preset value, let the user change it, if they input the wrong data it sets to default.

```
    func_set_num_files(){
        echo "How many files do you want to create? (input a number 1-10000)"
        read X
        # 1, is it a number, #2 is it within max range?
        if [[ $X != *[!0-9]* ]]; then

            if ((1<=X && X<=10000)) ;then
                        echo "NUM_FILES=$X"
                        NUM_FILES=$X
                else
                        echo "Invalid input, setting to default value [ $NUM_FILES ].";sleep 3
            fi

        else
            echo "Invalid input, non-numeric values entered, setting to default value [ $NUM_FILES ].";sleep 3
        fi

    }
```

Another example using 'case' to check that a variable is in a range of integers :

check that $MAX is a number and that it's between 50-100 :

```
            case $MAX in
                ''|*[!0-9]*)
                    echo "The value $MAX is not a number !"
                    exit 1
                ;;
                *)
                    if [ $MAX -lt 50 ] || [ $MAX -gt 100 ] ;then
                        echo "The value $MAX is not between 50-100"
                        exit 1
                    fi
                    echo "Looks like we are good !"
                ;;
            esac
```

Comment: Thanks for coming up with a way to state numerical range(s) in a `case` statement, rather than just suggesting that it needs to be an `if`.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is another solution (may be useful for anybody else):

```
function caseInRange {
  if [ $1 -ge $2 ]; then
    if [ $1 -lt $3 ]; then echo "$1"; else echo "too high"; fi
  else
    echo "to low"
  fi
}
case $MovieRes in
  1) echo "$MovieName" >> moviefinal ;;
  "$(caseInRange $MovieRes 460 660)") echo "$MovieName,480p" >> moviefinal ;;
  "$(caseInRange $MovieRes 660 890)") echo "$MovieName,720p" >> moviefinal ;;
  "$(caseInRange $MovieRes 890 1200)") echo "$MovieName,1080p" >> moviefinal ;;
  *) echo "$MovieName,DVD" >> moviefinal ;;
esac
```

This way you can mix ranges and fixed values.