# Complex expression in case in linux shell

Tags: linux, shell

i want to do something like ..
if mark is between 80-100 it will show A+
if mark is between 70-79 it will show A
etc

I want to do it with “case in esac” not with if-elif-fi

But how do I do complex expression in case

```
echo “enter mark”
read mark
case $mark in
(( mark>=80 && mark<=100 ))) echo “A+”
..
..
..
esac
```

i tried this. it is easy with if-elif-fi but what i should do in the 'case'
thank you.

Comment: This can help you!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614011/using-case-for-range-of-numbers-in-bash

Answer (score 3):

You don't specify a shell, so let me plug `zsh`:

```
#!/bin/zsh

echo “enter mark”
read mark
case $mark in
    <80-100>) echo "A+" ;;
    <70-79>) echo "A" ;;
    ...
esac
```

That said, the POSIX `case` statement (and the `case` statement in most shells) is geared towards matching text patterns, not arithmetic comparison. You *could* use a `case` statement, but it can get ugly.

```
case $mark in
    [89]?|100) echo "A+" ;;
    7?) echo "A" ;;
    ...
esac
```

It's not so bad in this case, since you don't have ranges like `65-74`, but an `if` statement would be better.

```
if (( mark >=80 && mark <=100 )); then
    echo "A+"
elif (( mark >=70 )); then
    echo "A"
elif ...; then
    ...
else
    ...
fi
```

Comment: (8|9)?|100) throws syntax error instead change it to [89]?|100)

Answer (score 1):

Use if condition its easier

```
if [[ ${mark} -ge 80 && ${mark} -le 100 ]]; then
        echo "A+"
fi
```

But if you still need case then you need to specify a pattern

```
case ${mark} in
8[0-9]|9[0-9]|100)
        echo  "A+"
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

In a regular POSIX-ish shell:

```
echo "enter mark"
read mark
case "$mark" in
([89][0-9]|100) echo "A+";;
(7[0-9])        echo "Grade";;
(6[0-9])        echo "Grade";;
...
esac
```

The leading open parenthesis on the expressions is optional.